# Docker volume mount is empty, when attempting to create volume

Tags: docker, containers, mount

Im pretty new to docker, i've set up a few containers on my raspberry pi - They are running a website and i'd like to save user images. If i read correctly i need to mount a directory in my docker container "/world" to a volume i create.

**I created the volume:** docker volume create images_test

**I attempted to link it using docker run:**

```
docker run -it --privileged=true -d --network nginxnetwork --name=schedule-events-backend berthelmaster0802/schedule-events-backend -v images_test:/world uname -m armv7l;
```

**My Dockerfile**:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app


COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore


COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "backend.dll"]
```

**When i inspect my container:**

```
docker inspect schedule-events-backend
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "8044b26c4ed7",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80",
                "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true"
            ],
```

My mount seems to be empty still. Anyone can figure out what im doing wrong?

Comment: Does the directory `/world` exist in you container image?

Comment: @MartinTovmassian Yes, it's in the same folder as the Dockerfile

Comment: When you say the the directory `/world` is in the same folder as the Dockerfile your are talking about what you have on your host machine right? But I'm not sure the *mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1* image has an embedded directory `/world`. You need to create it before running your container.

Comment: You've added the `-v` option after the image name, so it will be interpreted as the command to run and not a Docker option (you should see this in the `docker inspect` output too).  Move the option before the image name.

Comment: @MartinTovmassian yeah sorry, that was very inprecise. In my application i copy the folder /world into the publish folder (on build) - That can be done (and works) on my local machine. But im not sure if it works in docker. But when it's published it's in the same folder as the .dll file that is referenced in the Dockerfile (publish folder)

Comment: @DavidMaze Omg that actually worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidMaze solved the problem, thank you so much:
"You've added the -v option after the image name, so it will be interpreted as the command to run and not a Docker option (you should see this in the docker inspect output too). Move the option before the image name"